# How does definition of event horizon imply that they are null?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I am familiar with the definition of a (future) event horizon as the boundary of the closure of the causal past of the future null infinity. I am aware that event horizons are null hypersurfaces -- intuitively this makes sense if I think of the horizon as the surface at which the lightcones "tip" over 45 degrees, and all future causal paths lead to the singularity. I have never seen, however, a proof that $$\text{(event horizon = boundary of closure of causal past of future null infinity)} \Rightarrow \text{(null surface)}$$ i.e. that the definition above of an event horizon directly implies that it is also a null surface. I can intuitively see why it is the case, but it would be nice to see a proof of it, if anyone knows of one. Thanks.

Furthermore, does the arrow above also go the other way round $\Leftarrow$, i.e. does null surface imply the definition of event horizon?